# Sql server query optimizer seems to do something wrong

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization

```
SELECT
    My.id,
    SUM (CountResults.Quantity) as TotalQuantity
FROM 
    (SELECT
        My.*, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY My.Date DESC) AS RowNumber
     FROM [Test] My) My
OUTER APPLY
    (SELECT *
     FROM  ( /* really expensive query */ ) CR
     WHERE My.RowNumber = 1   
        /* I expect that optimizer will execute query only once for 1st row */
    ) CountResults
GROUP BY  
    My.id
```

What I really see, is that query takes much longer to execute then I would expect ( I measured time of a single execution of inner query and it's about 0.1s and my query executes much much longer)

Am I missing something?

PS: Plan in `.sqlplan` format  https://www.dropbox.com/s/vn6oy69z5xbuuug/Plan%201.sqlplan
of queries with `WHERE [My].[RowNumber] = 1` versus without.
As you can see, it says 50% to 50% and that's strange.

I've also tried:

```
LEFT JOIN
(   
   SELECT *  FROM  ( /* expensive query */ ) as [1]
) as CountResults ON My.RowNumber = 1
```

Nothing has changed.

Comment: If I substitute `[My].[RowNumber] = 1` with `1 = 2`, for instance, then everything works fast...

Comment: Side note: if you have multiple tables and nested subqueries - I would recommend **NOT** to give all of them the same table alias!

Comment: @marc_s that's just an example. but thank you.

Comment: What do the execution plans say? Pointless speculating rather than getting the actual plans that the different queries produce and comparing them.

Comment: Is there a convenient format for query plans? Because it's rather wide when saved as an image and dosn't fit to screen width...

Comment: When you say the inner query are you including the `OUTER APPLY`

Comment: I've added a link to execution plan in topic: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vn6oy69z5xbuuug/Plan%201.sqlplan

Comment: `[My] [eyes] [bleed] [from] [these] [ugly] [brackets] [.]`

Comment: O MY GOD OKAY, I'm removing the brackets not to harm your susceptible eyes! I hope now that things have drastically changed and you also have the execution plans, I really hope that i can get some help with my question!

Comment: Is there any correlation inside that outer apply query? It doesn't seems to be, so it could be rewritten as a simple `CROSS JOIN` and no `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @ypercube in reality query is more complex. What's puzzling me is why sql-server executes this query with overhead?

Comment: You didn''t answer the question. Is it correlated to the `My` table or not?

Comment: @ypercube yes, it' correlated to the `My` table

Comment: Show us the correlation then!

Comment: Is that an estimated plan or an actual plan? An estimated one wouldn't really help here.

Comment: @ArturUdod [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6) is _royalty_ compared to Dropbox...next time you could try that. And ask a question - "how to optimize the following query?" instead of "my sqlserver optimizer is wrong..." =) good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If the outer apply subquery is not correlated - which does not seem to be - then you don't have to use `OUTER APPLY`. You can rewrite with a simple `LEFT JOIN` and no `GROUP BY`, moving the aggregation inside the uncorrelated subquery:

```
SELECT
    My.id,
    CountResults.TotalQuantity
FROM 
    (SELECT
        My.id, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY My.Date DESC) AS RowNumber
     FROM [Test] My
    ) My
  LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT SUM(Quantity) AS TotalQuantity
     FROM  ( /* really expensive query */ ) CR
    ) CountResults
    ON  My.RowNumber = 1 ;
```